# "Move to trash" not working

Tags: 16.04, delete, trash

I just installed **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** on my notebook (ASUS ZenBook UX303U).
Whenever I try to "**Move to Trash**" a file it appears a window asking «*“MyFile” can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?*».

Consider I already used Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for long in another partition of the same notebook, and it gave me no such problem.

I feel like it can be a permission problem, but I don't really know how to fix this!

Comment: What is MyFile? Could it be a symbolic link created in an experiment using instructions of the internet?

Comment: It behaves the same with **any** file! May it be a .png, a .txt or a folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory you need to look at is `~/.local/share/Trash`.

You should be the owner of this directory and everything in it. If not, do `sudo chown -R username:username ~/.local/share/Trash`.

Its permissions, and those of all the directories in it, should be `drwx------`. If it isn't, do `chmod -R 700 ~/.local/share/Trash`.

Comment: After using `chmod -R 700 ~/.local/share/Trash` I moved with `cd` to `~/.local/share` with no problems. Then trying to access `Trash` I receive such a error: `bash: cd: Trash/: Permission denied`. Should I try with `777` instead? Or is it dangerous?

Comment: with `ls -l` inside `~/.local/share` I noticed that the folder `Trash` is the only one not owned by my user, but by the `root`! Here's what I see: `drwx------ 4 root   root   4096 set 25 15:00 Trash`

Comment: Added the command to correct that.