# Move to trash is not shown in context menu and item deleted permanently

Tags: 16.04, delete, context-menu

I have a problem. Move to trash is not shown in context menu. When I delete an item with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> then it asks for 'Are you sure you want to permanently delete “File or Folder Name”?', then I choose it and then deleted item not show in trash. Many times I have lost my personal data.

[image: Files]

I think if we change Delete preferences in Edit menu from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to <kbd>Delete</kbd>, then my problem is resolved.

What should I do?

Comment: What is the output of `locate --regex "/home.*Trash$" | xargs ls -ld` ?

Comment: Output :

drwx------ 4 mohit mohit 4096 Jul 17 17:38 /home/mohit/.local/share/Trash

Comment: Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829785/move-to-trash-not-working

Comment: I checked it and my setting for this is already same but still I have same problem.